# Spring Boot with Apigee and Okta

Tags: spring-boot, okta, apigee

I have been exploring APIgee and okta configuration using https://github.com/tom-smith-okta/okta-api-center repo. Here APIgee edge acts as a gateway to https://okta-solar-system.herokuapp.com/ api’s and the token for authentication is generated via okta. My understanding is that https://okta-solar-system.herokuapp.com/ doesnt have any okta authentication enforcement. The check is via apigee.

If I were to replace https://okta-solar-system.herokuapp.com/ with a spring boot application hosted publicly should the application have okta security enabled (eg : https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-oauth-example) or should i follow same procedure as above and delegate enforcement of token to apigee, without any security enforcement on the spring boot application?

Can someone tell me what is the standard way of implementation I should follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spring boot application has no enforcement of security, what is to prevent someone from bypassing the Apigee API gateway and calling it directly?

If you have successfully managed to secure the spring boot application so that only the API gateway can communicate with it (via mutual TLS connection, IP allow listing, etc), you might be able to forego any enforement at the service level, but I would recommend doing some authorization checks in the service itself.

Comment: What about implementing client credentials grant type between apigee and the spring boot app.

Comment: That would work, but you'd have to implement credential management in Apigee, as well as the token management (caching of token, dealing with invalidated tokens, etc).